# Is "!" intsead of "== 0" to check if int is 0 good practice?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Let's say we have a variable a:

```
int a = 0;
```

Is it okay to do

```
if(!a)
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

instead of

```
if(a == 0)
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

? Because it works.

In the first example the int will be turned into a bool, so is it okay to do it without `static_cast<bool>(a)`? Also what will happen if `a` is bigger than 1?

Comment: _"Is it okay to do

`if(!a)`"_ Sure.

Comment: Technically, all conditional clauses `if`/`while`/etc. doesn't even require `bool`. They only to be convertible to integral value, and then, if value is equal to zero - it is treated as false, and true - otherwise. But I, personally, prefer `if(a == 0)`, due to better readability. Also, questions about `good practice` are always opinion-based.

Comment: Sure it works and it's well defined by the standard - there's a conversion from int to bool in which 0 is taken to be false, and non-zero is taken to be true. But remember you're writing code for other humans (including yourself in the future) to read. Writing `if (a == 0)` is a more explicit statement of intent. Seasoned programmers will correctly interpret `if (!a)` identically, but the fact that you've asked this question highlights how problematic it can be when your statements don't reflect your high-level intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the first example the int will be turned into a bool, so is it okay to do it without `static_cast<bool>(a)`?

Yes it is okay.  There will be an implicit conversion.

> Also what will happen if `a` is bigger than 1?

any non 0 value is implicitly convertible to `true`.  Conversely only a value of 0 will be treated as `false`.

Which way should you chose? Either is fine.  I like to  express my intent with my code.  If I only want the if statement to run when `a` is equal to 0 the I prefer

```
if (a == 0)
```

as that shows exactly what I want.

Comment: I agree. And, whatever choice, keep it consistent.

Comment: @black totally.  Consistent use of constructs, indentation and white space is all very important.

Answer (score -1):

It's valid and people use it, but I would consider it far from good practice. It gives the wrong idea about the semantics of the value.

`0` is commonly treated *falsy*, but that is more of a relic from C days than anything else. Newer languages don't even allow it because it misleads readers of the code about what the value is.

Comment: _"0 is commonly treated falsy, but that is more of a relic from C days"_ No, 0 is false and 1 is true because it's from boolean algebra.

Comment: No, boolean algebra does not know `0` and `1`, it only knows `true` and `false`. `0` and `1` are sometimes used as shorthand values for those, but they are conceptually completely different.